# object vs string output

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Why is it when I run this command in powershell:

```
 $output = (svn stat) -match '^\?' # which $output is an [object] in this case.
```

I get this output in the PowerGUI Script Editor Console when viewing the variable $output:

```
?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest.txt
?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest - Copy.txt
```

but when I run this command:

```
[string] $output = (svn stat) -match '^\?'
```

I get these results:

```
?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest.txt ?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest - Copy.txt
```

It seems when using [string] it does some type of encoding where it takes away newlines and I'm not sure why?

**UPDATED**
user978511 here is the the small example code and output

```
Clear-Host
Set-Location "C:\svn\Development\Projects\TestProjects\build"
$output = (svn stat) -match '^\?'
'$output results'
$output

'$output2 results'
[string] $output2 = (svn stat) -match '^\?'
$output2
```

Output:

```
$output results
?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest.txt
?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest - Copy.txt
$output2 results
?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest.txt ?       Projects\TestProject\Thisisatest - Copy.txt
```

Thanks for anyone that can help.

Comment: And what behavior do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When PowerShell casts an array to a single string it converts the members to strings and concatenates them with spaces between each.

`$output2 = [string]::join([environment]::newline, $output)` will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  So (svn stat) -match '^\?' is returning an array of strings?

Comment: Most command line commands will provide feedback to the user with a sort of WriteLine method. When assigning the output to a variable, Powershell will store each line in an object and make an array out of it. The object array can be down casted to a string array. You can also use the `-join` operater to simplify the syntax jon provided. Here's an example using the `-join` operator: `$output2 = $output -join [environment]::newline`.